# Clamp addition evaluated early by Less

Tags: less, font-size, clamp

I am trying to use `clamp` for a `font-size` in my Less file. I set it to be `font-size: clamp(3.429rem, -1.870rem + 6.493vw, 9.143rem);`.

When I build my styles however, I end up with CSS looking like `font-size: clamp(3.429rem, 4.623rem, 9.143rem);`. Less is evaluating the addition instead of passing over the whole `clamp` expression into CSS. I find this odd since there is no view width at build time.

How do I get Less to simply pass the `clamp` expression into the CSS file without evaluating?